# How do you watch for changes in letsencrypts certbot-created certificates in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, express, lets-encrypt, certbot

So my current setup is:

I have an apache2 server that is set up to work with auto-renewal through certbot, however I also want to use the certificate for my node server that is running on the same machine.

So far so good, the cert is updating regularly, but every time it renews, it creates a new pem file, so I cannot simply watch the file for changes to update the secure context of my NodeJS express server. I tried watching the link that always links to the latest pem file in the live/ folder of the letsencrypt folder, but that never fires, not through fileSystem.watch, nor through fileSystem.watchFile.

Is there some way I can watch the link? This is absurdly annoying to test as I need to wait a few months for a new cert to be created to check if my server is updating the secure context correctly.

Or do I just have to bite the bullet and regularly read the link and see if it matches the last time I checked?

Comment: I'd be stunned if there wasn't already an [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com) package for this very thing.